# Evaluating $\int \sqrt{\frac{x^2+1}{x^2(1-x^2)}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

> Today I came across the following integral
> $$\int \sqrt{\frac{x^2+1}{x^2(1-x^2)}}dx$$

---

**Here's my work:**
$$\begin{align}\int \sqrt{\frac{x^2+1}{x^2(1-x^2)}}dx& = \int\frac{1}{x} \sqrt{\frac{1+x^2}{1-x^2}}\ dx \\ & =  -\int \sqrt{\frac{1+\cos(2\theta)}{1 - \cos(2\theta)}} \tan(2\theta) \ d\theta\tag{$*$}\\& = -\int \sqrt{\frac{2\cos^2(\theta)}{2\sin^2(\theta)}}\cdot \frac{\sin(2\theta)}{\cos(2\theta)} \ d\theta\\& = - \int\frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}\cdot \frac{2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)}{\cos^2\theta - \sin^2\theta}\ d\theta\\& = - \int \frac{(\cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta) + (\cos^2\theta - \sin^2\theta)}{\cos^2\theta - \sin^2\theta}\ d\theta\\& = - \int \sec(2\theta) + 1 \ d\theta\tag{1}\\& =-\frac{1}2 \ln|\sec(2\theta) + \tan(2\theta)| + \theta + C\tag{2}\\& = - \frac{1}{2} \ln\left|\sec(\cos^{-1}(x^2)) + \tan(\cos^{-1}(x^2))\right|  + \frac12 \cos^{-1}(x^2) + C\\& = - \frac12\ln\left|\frac1{x^2} + \frac{\sqrt{1 - x^4}}{x^2}\right| + \frac12 \cos^{-1}(x^2) + C\\& = - \frac12\ln\left|\frac{1 + \sqrt{1 - x^4}}{x^2}\right| + \frac12 \cos^{-1}(x^2) + C\end{align}$$

---

> $(*)$ Here I've made a substitution $x^2 = \cos(2\theta)$ so that $\dfrac{dx}{x} = - \tan(2\theta)\ d\theta$.

---

But this answer seems to be wrong! I differentiated my answer but didn't get the original integrand. Wolframalpha results [this expression](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Integrate+sqrt%28%28x%5E2%2B1%29%2F%28x%5E2%281-x%5E2%29%29%29) and I'm not sure about it.

I'm just unable to figure out what's actually wrong with my method.

> > **Edit:**
> >
> > With Bob Dobbs's comment, I got that I did wrong moving from step $(1)$ to step $(2)$.

Comment: Substitution isn't the best choice. Try $x = cosh(t)$, where $dx = sinh(t) dt$

Comment: @rumathe Thanks for the suggestion. I wish if you could also tell me what's wrong with my substitution.

Comment: Your substitution $x^2 = \cos(2\theta)$ is almost correct, but it is not valid for $x\in(-1,0)\cup(0,1)$. This is because the range of the cosine function is $[-1,1]$, so the expression $\cos(2\theta)$ is always between $-1$ and $1$. Therefore, if $x^2=\cos(2\theta)$, then $x^2$ must also be between $-1$ and $1$, which is not the case for $x\in(-1,0)\cup(0,1)$. To fix this issue, you can use a slightly different substitution. Let $x=\sin\theta$, so $x^2=\sin^2\theta$ and $\sqrt{1-x^2}=\cos\theta$.

Comment: I'm not well versed with hyperbolic functions. So I'm not sure if I could take that home.

Comment: It is a sign mistake. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28-%281%2F2%29ln%28%281%2Bsqrt%281-x%5E4%29%29%2Fx%5E2%29-%281%2F2%29cos%5E%28-1%29%28x%5E2%29%29%27

Comment: @BobDobbs Aah... I got my mistake. I did wrong after the step $$- \int \sec(2\theta) + 1\ d\theta$$. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The back trigonometric substitution could be problematic. To avoid it, integrate instead as follows

$$\int \sqrt{\frac{x^2+1}{x^2(1-x^2)}}dx=
\int \frac x{\sqrt{1-x^4}}dx+\int \frac1{\sqrt{x^2(1-x^4})}dx
$$
where
\begin{align}
&\int \frac x{\sqrt{1-x^4}}dx=\frac12\int \frac {d(x^2)}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}=\frac12\sin^{-1}x^2\\
 &\int \frac 1{\sqrt{x^2(1-x^4})}dx=\frac12\int \frac {d(\sqrt{1-x^4})}{(1-x^4)-1}=-\frac12\tanh^{-1} \sqrt{1-x^4}
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

If you make
$$x=\sqrt{\frac {t^2-1}{t^2+1 }}$$ the integral becomes
$$-2\int \frac{t^2}{t^4-1}\,dt $$ Factoring and partial fraction decomposition
$$\frac{t^2}{t^4-1}=\frac{t^2}{(t^2-1)(t^2+1)}=\frac{1}{2 \left(t^2+1\right)}+\frac{1}{2 \left(t^2-1\right)}$$ which are simple

Answer (score 1):

Assume $x>0$ We need to find $$\int\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$ Substitute $u=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ and rewrite the integral as $$\int\frac{\sqrt{2-u^2}}{u^2-1}du$$ Substitute $v=\sqrt2\sin v$ and rewrite the integral as $$\int\frac{\sqrt2\cos v\sqrt{2-2\sin^2v}}{2\sin^2v-1}dv$$ $$=2\int\frac{\cos^2v}{2\sin^2v-1}dv$$ Recall that $\sin v=\frac{\tan v}{\sec v}$ and $\cos v=\frac{1}{\sec v}$ and $\tan^2v=\sec^2v-1$

Now our integral becomes (Just solving the integral, we can multiply by $2$ later) $$\int\frac{\sec^2v}{(\tan^2v-1)(\tan^2v+1)}dv$$ Substitute $w=\tan v$ and rewrite as $$\int\frac{1}{(w^2-1)(w^2+1)}dw$$ Using parial fraction we can rewrite it as $$\int\left[\frac{1}{4(w-1)}-\frac{1}{4(w+1)}-\frac{1}{2(w^2+1)}\right]dw$$
I hope OP can continue from here.

Note: After you evaluate the final answer, don't forget it to multiply by $\frac{x}{|x|}$